# When deploying .NET applications - how do you find out what zone a share is in relative to the computer running the application?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Using any version of .NET how do you find out which zone a particular share is classified under. I am having a problem identifying if a share where my referenced dlls reside is in the "intranet zone" or "internet" zone relative to some user machine that is running my .NET application. I suspect this is a problem because I am having a problem accessing referenced dlls from a share on some machines but not others. How can I tell which zone .NET is classifying that share in so I can adjust permissions accordingly?

Comment: Do you need to find out programmatically, or just from a diagnostic perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically you can use [IInteretSecurty::MapZoneToUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537133%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which is a COM interface.  There is an example at [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/interfaces/iinternetsecuritymanager.html) of defining and calling it from C# and Vb.net.

I created and tested a simpler example of calling MapZoneToUrl from C# based on the pinvoke.net sample and the MSDN example.

The url needs to start with an http:// or https:// or else you will get an E_INVALIDARG error, so I don't know what that means for checking network shares.

```
public static class InternetSecurityManager
{
    private static Guid _CLSID_SecurityManager = new Guid("7b8a2d94-0ac9-11d1-896c-00c04fb6bfc4");
    private static string[] ZoneNames = new[] { "Local", "Intranet", "Trusted", "Internet", "Restricted" };

    public static string GetUrlZone(string url)
    {
        Type t = System.Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(_CLSID_SecurityManager);
        IInternetSecurityManager securityManager = (IInternetSecurityManager)System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        try
        {
            uint zone = 0;
            int hResult = securityManager.MapUrlToZone(url, ref zone, 0);
            if (hResult != 0)
                throw new COMException("Error calling MapUrlToZone, HRESULT = " + hResult.ToString("x"), hResult);

            if (zone < ZoneNames.Length)
                return ZoneNames[zone];
            return "Unknown - " + zone;
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(securityManager);
        }
    }
}

[ComImport, GuidAttribute("79EAC9EE-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B")]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IInternetSecurityManager
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetSecuritySite([In] IntPtr pSite);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSecuritySite([Out] IntPtr pSite);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int MapUrlToZone([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszUrl,
             ref UInt32 pdwZone, UInt32 dwFlags);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSecurityId([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszUrl,
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pbSecurityId,
              ref UInt32 pcbSecurityId, uint dwReserved);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int ProcessUrlAction([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszUrl,
             UInt32 dwAction, out byte pPolicy, UInt32 cbPolicy,
             byte pContext, UInt32 cbContext, UInt32 dwFlags,
             UInt32 dwReserved);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int QueryCustomPolicy([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszUrl,
              ref Guid guidKey, ref byte ppPolicy, ref UInt32 pcbPolicy,
              ref byte pContext, UInt32 cbContext, UInt32 dwReserved);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetZoneMapping(UInt32 dwZone,
               [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszPattern,
               UInt32 dwFlags);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetZoneMappings(UInt32 dwZone, out UCOMIEnumString ppenumString,
            UInt32 dwFlags);
}
```

Comment: What assembly to I add in for IInternetSecurity?  I can't seem to get this working without that.

Comment: IInternetSecurity is an unmanaged COM type, there is no .NET assembly for it.  There no assembly to reference and it can't be added to a .NET project.  That's why the code above had to manually declare IInternetSecurityManager and System.Type.GetTypeFromCLSID() to instantiate it.